# Updating shapefile metadata to show up in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcobjects, metadata, arccatalog

I am attempting to update the [metadata](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/metadata/the-arcgis-metadata-format.htm) for a variety of shapefiles to change the information under 'Summary' (or 'Purpose'), 'Description' (or 'Abstract'), etc. in ArcCatalog's Description tab.

I am using ArcMap 10.4 and am working in C#.

I can already update the Metadata itself and I can see that my changes have been applied to the shapefile's .shp.xml file, but this doesn't consistently change the info in ArcCatalog's Description tab. Looking at several shapefiles I have been given, it seems that there is some other setting that dictates where the ArcCatalog pulls its information from.

For example here are two different paths for two different shapefiles from where ArcCatalog gets the Description:

> idinfo/descript/abstract
>
> dataIdInfo/idAbs

The values for those elements are unique to the file, so there is nowhere else the data could be getting pulled from.

What do I need to set in my shapefiles to make ArcCatalog look at a consistent location for it's sections?

Comment: Did you try [upgrading](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/metadata/the-arcgis-metadata-format.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C008B1D2B4A242F79E5765D498A9B3A9) the metadata to arcgis format?